# Matching JSON Feed to Webpage Content with JavaScript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am attempting to match a JSON feed to content that exists on a webpage -- a very simple explanation, if the vehicle listed on the page matches a vehicle in the JSON feed, log the offer to the console.

My code so far:

```
var url = 'http://specials.baxterauto.com/jsonkick.php';
var vehicle = document.querySelector('.ddc-page-title').innerHTML;
if( vehicle = '2016 Subaru Forester 2.5i Limited' ) {
  $.getJSON( url, function( data ) {
    Object.keys( data ).forEach(function( k ) {
        if( k = "2016 Subaru Forester 2.5i Limited" ) {
            console.log( data[0].OfferType + " " + data[0].OfferValue );
        }
    })
  })           
};
```

This returns the first value listed for `OfferType` and `OfferValue` within the feed, but these are not the correct values associated with a "2016 Subaru Forester 2.5i Limited".

How can I get the correct key value to return?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you should replace `if k = "2016...` by `if k == "2016...` and `data[0]` by `data[k]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By taking `data[0]` you are assuming that the match was on the first item. Try adding an iterator so that you can use it to keep track of which item you are on, and selecting that one. Example:

```
var url = 'http://specials.baxterauto.com/jsonkick.php';
var vehicle = document.querySelector('.ddc-page-title').innerHTML;
if( vehicle = '2016 Subaru Forester 2.5i Limited' ) {
  $.getJSON( url, function( data ) {
    Object.keys( data ).forEach(function( k, i ) {
        if( k === "2016 Subaru Forester 2.5i Limited" ) {
            console.log( data[i].OfferType + " " + data[i].OfferValue );
        }
    })
  })           
};
```